# Blur the image on real-time where user touches

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es, coronasdk, blur

I want to blur the portion of the image where user touches on real-time in Android. The native canvas approach is not suitable in this case i guess, as the blur result I want is real-time & based on the touch movement hence the performance will lag.
openGL / its framework Corona SDK may help me, but I'm not sure how to approach them.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. And personally, I'd prefer Canvas for operations with bitmaps, like blurring a part of image.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime filters is coming in Graphics 2.0 later this summer.